# return a value from a JFrame to main()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I am writing a program which has a JFrame with a JMenu in it. Once the user clicks a menuItem, a JDialog is being called, to get a String from the user. I want to use that string in my main programm but i don't know how to return that value from the JFrame to the main programm (I managed to return the value from the JDialog to the JFrame). Any ideas?

**My main::**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    myFirstFrame m = new myFirstFrame();

    m.setVisible(true);

    String localhost = m.getLh();

    System.out.println(localhost);
}
```

**My JFrame::**

```
public class myFirstFrame extends JFrame
{
    String lh;

    myDialog myD;

    public myFirstFrame(JFrame mf)
    {
        super();
        setTitle("Welcome");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuItem playg = new JMenuItem("Play game");
        simetoxi.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                myD = new myDialog(myFirstFrame.this);
                myD.setVisible(true);

                String lh = myD.getText();
                System.out.println(lh + "ASasASas");
                dispose();
            }

        });

        JMenu game = new JMenu("GAME");
        game.add(playg);
        JMenuBar myBar = new JMenuBar();
        myBar.add(game);
        setJMenuBar(myBar);
    }

    public String getLh()
    {
        return lh;
    }
}
```

**My JDialog::**

```
public class myDialog extends JDialog
{
    JTextField t1;

    String sname;

    public myDialog(JFrame fr)
    {
        super(fr, true);
        setTitle("Connect");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Give the server name");
        t1 = new JTextField(15);
        add(l1);
        add(t1);
        JButton okb = new JButton("submit");
        okb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                sname = t1.getText();
                dispose();
            }
        });
        add(okb);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return sname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you start running the Swing application as specified here as Application Startup: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml then you don't need to communicate with the main() function, anything from that point is the JFrame's and its children's responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `main` creates the `Frame`, it doesn't stop and wait for the value to become available before executing the rest of the `main` function.

There are many ways you could solve this problem. For example, rather than putting `System.out.println(localhost)` in `main`, you could put it in a different method. Then, in the `Frame`, call that method when you get the value.

If you really want to put that call in `main`, you will have to find some way to make `main` block until the value is available. For example, you could create a `BlockingQueue`, and try to dequeue the value from within `main`. In the `Frame` event handler, push the needed value onto the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The main method will not wait for your JFrame to go through those steps, so calling a getter in your main program (even if you "correct"

```
 String lh = myD.getText();
```

to

```
 lh == myD.getText();
```

will not work. - Pass this information to a class/method that makes good use of it, perhaps processing it in a separate thread - depends of what you want to do with "localhost".